# Null reference in a foreach over "Table.Rows"

Tags: c#, .net

In the line `foreach (DataRow Row in Table.Rows)`, I'm getting a NullReferenceException.

The program is in an emulator in C#.  When I debug it and it crashes, it highlights the word `foreach` in yellow.  I've pasted my whole code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;

using Reality.Storage;
using System.Threading;

namespace Reality.Game.Moderation
{
    public static class ModerationBanManager
    {
        private static List<uint> mCharacterBlacklist;
        private static List<string> mRemoteAddressBlacklist;
        private static Thread mWorkerThread;
        private static object mSyncRoot;

        public static void Initialize(SqlDatabaseClient MySqlClient)
        {
            mCharacterBlacklist = new List<uint>();
            mRemoteAddressBlacklist = new List<string>();
            mSyncRoot = new object();

            mWorkerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProcessThread));
            mWorkerThread.Name = "ModerationBanManager";
            mWorkerThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
            mWorkerThread.Start();

            ReloadCache(MySqlClient);
        }

        public static void ProcessThread()
        {
            try
            {
                while (Program.Alive)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(600000);

                    using (SqlDatabaseClient MySqlClient = SqlDatabaseManager.GetClient())
                    {
                        ReloadCache(MySqlClient);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException) { }
            catch (ThreadInterruptedException) { }
        }

        public static void ReloadCache(SqlDatabaseClient MySqlClient)
        {
            lock (mSyncRoot)
            {
                mCharacterBlacklist.Clear();
                mRemoteAddressBlacklist.Clear();

                MySqlClient.SetParameter("timestamp", UnixTimestamp.GetCurrent());
                DataTable Table = MySqlClient.ExecuteQueryTable("SELECT * FROM bans WHERE timestamp_expire > @timestamp");

                foreach (DataRow Row in Table.Rows)
                {
                    uint UserId = (uint)Row["user_id"];
                    string RemoteAddr = (string)Row["remote_address"];

                    if (UserId > 0 && !mCharacterBlacklist.Contains(UserId))
                    {
                        mCharacterBlacklist.Add(UserId);
                    }

                    if (RemoteAddr.Length > 0 && !mRemoteAddressBlacklist.Contains(RemoteAddr))
                    {
                        mRemoteAddressBlacklist.Add(RemoteAddr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static bool IsRemoteAddressBlacklisted(string RemoteAddressString)
        {
            lock (mSyncRoot)
            {
                return mRemoteAddressBlacklist.Contains(RemoteAddressString);
            }
        }

        public static bool IsUserIdBlacklisted(uint UserId)
        {
            lock (mSyncRoot)
            {
                return mCharacterBlacklist.Contains(UserId);
            }
        }

        public static void BanUser(SqlDatabaseClient MySqlClient, uint UserId, string MessageText, uint ModeratorId)
        {
            MySqlClient.SetParameter("userid", UserId);
            MySqlClient.SetParameter("reason", MessageText);
            MySqlClient.SetParameter("timestamp", UnixTimestamp.GetCurrent());
            MySqlClient.SetParameter("timestampex", UnixTimestamp.GetCurrent());
            MySqlClient.SetParameter("moderator", ModeratorId);
            MySqlClient.ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO bans (user_id,reason_text,timestamp_created,timestamp_expire,moderator_id) VALUES (@userid,@reason,@timestamp,@timestampex,@moderator)");

            lock (mSyncRoot)
            {
                mCharacterBlacklist.Add(UserId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most people will not read through this much code. Try to post the minimal amount of code necessary to illustrate your problem

Comment: `DataTable Table` you should rename this variable to not conflict with the class name `Table`

Answer (score 5):

If it's really being thrown at this line:

```
foreach (DataRow Row in Table.Rows)
```

Then `Table` or `Table.Rows` is null.  If it is being thrown from inside of your foreach loop:

```
foreach (DataRow Row in Table.Rows) 
{
   //aka in here
}
```

Then it most likely means that one of your rows is null.  To find which one add this at the beginning of your loop and place a break point inside of the if statement.

```
foreach (DataRow Row in Table.Rows) 
{
   if(Row == null)
   {
       //breakpoint here!
   }

}
```

You can also just examine Table.Rows while debugging, but if there are 1000s of rows this is not a realistic option.

Comment: btw, the foreach will throw also when `Rows` is null

Comment: when you say //breakpoint here!, would i have to code a breakpoint? or just add that code.. sorry if i seem not to know much im basic with c#

Comment: Just right click on the line where you want the breakpoint, mouse over the "Breakpoint" submenu and select "Insert Breakpoint".

Answer (score 4):

If you have NullReferenceException in that exact line, this means that either the `Table` variable or the `Rows` property is `null`. There are almost no other options. Please put a breakpoint there and check which one of them is null - and then investigate and correct that.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing in the line that I'd imagine throwing a null reference exception, is if `Table` is `null`.

```
foreach (DataRow Row in Table.Rows)
```

---

when the exception is thrown and the line is highlighted, you're in the debugger.

When you're in the debugger, at the very bottom of your screen, You'll see a tab called `Watch` or `Watch`.  click on that tab.

In the box at the bottom, type the word `Table` and press enter, and it should show you the value of `Table`  I'll bet that's null.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [DataTable documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx), the constructor you're calling is expecting a `String` object *to use as the name for the table*.  It does not actually load the table.

The best way to use a DataTable is to initialize your DataTable (for example, `DataTable table = new DataTable()`), then use the .Add() method of the Rows properties to add to it.  To illustrate, you could use the following code inside a foreach loop that iterates through the mySql query results:

`table.Rows.Add(item)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you debugged this and made sure that your DataTable is not actually null?

What does the following return?  your problem is likely in that line of code, not in the for/each

```
DataTable Table = MySqlClient.ExecuteQueryTable("SELECT * FROM bans WHERE timestamp_expire > @timestamp");
```